# why built in method to getcurrentposition not working on my website

Tags: javascript, geolocation, hosting

i put in a code to my browser and
this code working in my liveserver, but don't wanna working on my website i have hosting from infinitefree:

```
const bat = document.querySelector('.location')

const geolocation = () => {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

      var url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude;
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          const city = data.address.city;
          const street = data.address.road
          bat.innerHTML = ('City: ' + city) + '<br>' + ('Street: ' + street);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          bat.innerText = ('Error:', error);
        });
    });
  } else {
    bat.innerText = ('Geolocation is not supported by this browser');
  }
}

bat.addEventListener('click', geolocation)
```

how can i solve this problem

Comment: Have you checked your errors in the console for anything?

Comment: JS runs on the client, the server host shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: But browser security enables features like geolocation on a per-site basis. Maybe you've disabled it on your hosting server. Try clearing the site data.

Comment: conole don't show any errors in liveserver everything works fine